# how to open edit text on specific item is selected from spinner

Tags: android

I build a spinner in which i put element through array list and .i store the value of get selcted item from spinner in a variable,in my spinner it having 15 element,now i want to try when a specific item is selected from spinner then a dialog box is open with edit text and button then user can edit and save it in spinner.how can i do this.

my code for spinner is

```
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.faultid);

              addItemsOnSpinner2();
       addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

                     }


      public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection()
        {

            Spinner faultSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            mspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
                     CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

        }

                  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

             ArrayList<String> faulttypespinner = new ArrayList<String>();
             faulttypespinner.add("XL-Cross Level");
             faulttypespinner.add("AL-Alignment");
             faulttypespinner.add("UN-Unevenness");
             faulttypespinner.add("XL-Cross Level");
             faulttypespinner.add("AL-Alignment");
             faulttypespinner.add("UN-Unevenness");
             faulttypespinner.add("BD-Ballast Deficiency");
             faulttypespinner.add("SE-Super elevation on curve");
             faulttypespinner.add("LP-Loose Packing");
             faulttypespinner.add("LJ-Low Joint");
             faulttypespinner.add("BA-Bridge");
             faulttypespinner.add("LC-Level Crossing");
             faulttypespinner.add("LJ-Low Joint");
             faulttypespinner.add("P and C-Point n Xing");
             faulttypespinner.add("OTH-Other Defect");
             faulttypespinner.add("SEJ-SEJ");
             faulttypespinner.add("WEED-Weed on Cess");

           ArrayAdapter<String> faultadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
          (mConetxt,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, faulttypespinner);

    faultadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             mspinner.setAdapter(faultadapter);


 }

      public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
            "OnItemSelectedListener : " + 
             parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: your question is incomplete what and where u want store the data from edittext box

Comment: sir in my spinner when user select "OTH-Other Defect" then open a dialog box with edit text button then it store on spinner as well current element in spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to `implement Custom Adapter`, where you'll have a method something like :

```
public void changeItemValue(int position, String newValue){
    Item itm = getItem(position);
    itm.setValue(newValue);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When you open the `dialogBox` `onSelectedItem`, you'll have to pass an `instance` of your `spinner adapter` to a `dialog` and then to the `listener` of a `dialog button`, where you'll `call` `changeItemValue method` on `button click`.

Comment: sir please edit in my code or give some reference please sir.icant understand how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Why u r using custom adapter,when click on spinner get the position of clicked item and show the pop up and on button click set the value to the faulttypespinner arraylist using index stored previously. then add notifydatasetchanged for adapter to update the spinner thats all.

Comment: you r right sir but i cant understand how i open popup on specific item is selected from spinner